# static local variable in inline function causes hang in VS2015-compiled code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, static, inline

I have a legacy code along these lines:

```
inline A::A() {
    static boost::shared_ptr<Data> data(new Data(""));
    data_ = data;
}
```

`Data` is some class and `data_` is a non-static member variable of `class A`.  I am not sure what was the idea of the original coder here, but the interesting thing is that this code works fine when built with Visual Studio 2013 but when it is built with Visual Studio 2015, the code hangs (on the line where the static variable `data` is initialized) at the time of the DLL loading.
The reason the code is being called at the time of DLL loading is that there are static objects of `class A`, e.g,

```
class B
{
 static A a_;
}
```

I realize that VS2015 may build the code differently, for example, by not honoring the inline hint etc. But what would be the reason for it to hang? Is it some memory corruption? 
Not trying to make this code work - rather trying to understand the potential issue that this code could have caused.

Comment: I am not sure this is doable (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example) - this code is part of a giant solution. I am looking to understand the theoretical issue that could have caused it, not necessarily to solve the problem that this code is trying to achieve. It is possible that it isn't reproducible with any consistency.

Comment: We need to see the context in which this function is getting called. It would also help to know what the constructor of `Data` actually does. There's nothing in the posted code that would give us any clue what the issue is.

Comment: Hard to say for sure without seeing the rest of code, but looks like _static initialization order fiasco_ (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)

Comment: The odds of anyone being able to help you find a solution with three lines of code is extremely low. There are some god-level programmers stalking the fields here, but even they have limits.

Comment: Why is this code being called while the DLL is loading?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Let me see if I can come up with a better context. But judging from your input, it is not a obvious, smack-your-head issue, so, that's already very helpful!

Comment: The reason the code is being called is that the DLL has a bunch of static objects that use the class A. So, the suggestion that it is static initialization fiasco seems likely.

Comment: @PeterD Probably due to some detail of how the `Data` constructor works.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Huh, how did it escape me! The constructor of Data indeed is to blame - Data itself has a member variable of type A! Completely missed that. I feel embarrassed for asking the question and not investigating enough. Now I am just not sure how on earth it ever managed to work when compiled by VS2013...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for David Schwartz for suggesting the solution in the comments to the original question.
The issue was not due to any interaction of `static` local variable and `inline` hint in the constructor, as I assumed. Instead the issue was invocation of the constructor of `Data`, since `Data` has a member variable of type `A`. This causes circularity (`A`, to be created, needs `Data`, which needs `A`)
The issue is resolved by using [Named Constructor Idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom) thus:

```
class A{
  public:       
    static A createDefault()
    {
       static boost::shared_ptr<Data> data(new Data(""));
        A a;
        a.data_ = data;
        return a;
    }

  protected: 
    //Make the c'tor protected so that nobody uses it by mistake (except for derived classes) 
    A(){}

    //Struct Data can access A::A():
    struct Data{
       A a_;
       Data(string str) 
       {
           //...
       }
       //...
    };
};
```

Anywhere else:

```
//...
A a(A::createDefault());//or similar
//...
```

The one mystery that remains is how VS2013 managed to build it so that the code was running fine.